# Python regex to find {}

Tags: python, json, regex

I am going through a json file and using a regex to pull out info around company financial KPIs and their corresponding values.  For example, the regex for
`"grossProfits":{"raw":19805000000,"fmt":"19.8B","longFmt":"19,805,000,000"}`

would return the 19.8B.  The issue is when the KPI does not have any info.  For example 
`"returnOnEquity":{}`.

In this case returnOnEquity would return the next number the regex finds.
`"returnOnEquity":{},"grossProfits":{"raw":19805000000,"fmt":"19.8B","longFmt":"19,805,000,000"}`.

So the value returned for returnOnEquity will be that of grossProfits (19.8B).

Here is my current regex `r'.*?"(\d{1,8}\.\d{1,8}M?B?K?|[{}])%?'`

In a perfect world, I would want it to return 0 but even a '{' or '}' will suffice.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use the `json` module?

Comment: To elaborate, using the `json` module will make that a python dictionary, and there's no need at all to try parse this with regex. Just use the keys to get at your data.

Comment: Use the `json` module.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the earlier commentators, the `json` module is the way to go (see [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html))

In your case,

```
import json

with open('sample.txt') as js:
    data = json.load(js)

for firm in data:
    print(firm)
    print(data[firm]['grossProfits']['raw'])
    print(data[firm]['returnOnEquity'])
```

It turns your data into a dictionary of dictionaries, so you don't have to worry about parsing.